# Not able to set input value, when I use 'updateOn' attribute with form Control

Tags: angular, angular-test, angular-testing-library

I am doing testing using https://testing-library.com/

Here is my Reactive form:

```
this.createForm = this.formBuilder.group({
 'Id': new FormControl({ value: 0, disabled: true }, [Validators.required]),
 'Name': new FormControl('', { validators: [ValidationService.required, ValidationService.SubsystemMxLenght, ValidationService.SubsystemPatternMatch], updateOn: 'blur' }),
'UpdatedByName': new FormControl({ value: this.appUserName, disabled: true }, []),
 'UpdatedDate': new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [])
```

});

from the library's recommendation, I am setting value to form field like this:

```
component.input(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-1'), {
        target: {
            value: data.Name /* value not setting since we use updateOn value, so it's null */
        }
    });

    component.input(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-2'), {
        target: {
            value: data.UpdatedByName
        }
    });
```

In which I am not able to set the value with `Name`, If I remove the param `updateOn: 'blur'` - from the form, it sets. how to fix this? what is the issue with my form otherwise?

any one help me please?

**UPDATE:**
component function:

```
onCreateFormSubmit() {

 this.ssCreated.emit(created);

}
```

testing both `onCreateFormSubmit` and `ssCreated` - but `ssCreated` not works:

spec file:

```
test('Testing add Subsystem operation', async () => {

    const data = {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'subsystem2',
        IsDeletePossible: true,
        CreatedBy: '',
        CreatedDate: new Date(),
        UpdatedBy: '',
        UpdatedDate: new Date(),
        UpdatedByName: 'test value',
        CreatedByName: ''
    } as ModelSubSystem;

    const ssCreated = jest.fn();

    const component = await render(SubSystemComponent, {
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            StoreModule.forRoot({}, { runtimeChecks: { strictStateImmutability: true, strictActionImmutability: true } }),
            StoreModule.forFeature('pfservice', reducer),
            EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
            EffectsModule.forFeature([EffectsSubSystem])
        ],
        componentProperties: {
            onCreateFormSubmit: jest.fn(),
            ssCreated: {
                emit: data
            } as any,
        }

    });

    const componentInstance = component.fixture.componentInstance;


    /*
     *   Testing the form by DOM.
     */

    const createButton = component.getByTestId('btn-addRow');
    component.click(createButton);
    component.fixture.detectChanges();
    // status changes because of click on button
    expect(componentInstance.crud.isCreate).toBeTruthy();

    component.fixture.detectChanges();
    // onclick submit should not called, becasue of empty input

    component.input(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-0'), {
        target: {
            value: data.Id
        }
    });

    component.input(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-1'), {
        target: {
            value: data.Name
        }
    });


    component.blur(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-1'));

    component.input(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-2'), {
        target: {
            value: data.UpdatedByName
        }
    });

    const submit = component.getAllByTestId('form-create-btn')[0];

    component.click(submit);

    component.fixture.detectChanges();
    const name = componentInstance.createForm.controls['Name'];
    const updatedByName = componentInstance.createForm.controls['UpdatedByName'];
    expect(name.value).toEqual(data.Name);
    expect(name.errors).toBeFalsy();
    expect(updatedByName.value).toEqual(data.UpdatedByName);
    expect(componentInstance.onCreateFormSubmit).toBeCalled(); //works

    // console.log(componentInstance.createForm.getRawValue());
    console.log(data);

    expect(ssCreated).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data); //not works

});
```

Comment: `data`  variable is coming from where ? in this line `target:{value:data.Name}`

Comment: @GaurangDhorda - I have the static data is spec file. `data.UpdatedByName` - works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateOne` will only fire when the input is blurred, that's why you'll have to do:

```
component.input(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-1'), {
        target: {
            value: data.Name
        }
    });

// this line here
component.blur(component.getByTestId('form-create-name-field-1'));
```

I created an example here https://github.com/testing-library/angular-testing-library/commit/6989a66cfe2d0dfb66dcbb9566bf122307edca6c

Comment: I need to call a component method, the method trigger a emits with value. how to test both? can you share any sample please? on submit for it's happening

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you elaborate?
Also, you shouldn't have to call a component method directly, instead it should be executed via a DOM event.

Comment: can you please check my update in question? I am trying to capture the `emit` method with passing data by equalizing